# Are there any HashMap implementations with consistent ordering between program runs?

Tags: hashmap, rust

I've observed that `HashMap` has a different order of elements even with the same data on the next program start. It looks like `HashMap` uses some absolute addresses to sort elements. Is there any other `HashMap` implementation, which has the same behaviour if the same data was inserted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe [linked-hash-map](https://github.com/contain-rs/linked-hash-map) is the de facto crate for this.

Comment: The original post did not mention maintaining insertion order as necessary, but maintaining *consistent* order. If that's the requirement, I think using an alternate hash function as suggested by @Shepmaster is preferable as you're likely to get better performance.

Answer (score 11):

> I've observed that `HashMap` has a different order of elements even with the same data on the next program start.

You don't have to *observe* anything, this is [*documented by `HashMap`*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html):

> By default, `HashMap` uses a hashing algorithm selected to provide resistance against HashDoS attacks. The algorithm is randomly seeded, and a reasonable best-effort is made to generate this seed from a high quality, secure source of randomness provided by the host without blocking the program.

It's worth noting that this means that two `HashMap`s with the same set of inserted values in the *same program run* will likely have different ordering:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
    let a = (0..100).zip(100..200);

    let hash_one: HashMap<_, _> = a.clone().collect();
    let hash_two: HashMap<_, _> = a.clone().collect();

    // prints "false", most of the time
    println!("{}", hash_one.into_iter().eq(hash_two));
}
```

The documentation also tells you how to address the problem:

> The hashing algorithm can be replaced on a per-`HashMap` basis using the `default`, `with_hasher`, and `with_capacity_and_hasher` methods. Many alternative algorithms are available on crates.io, such as the fnv crate.

Since I worked on [twox-hash](https://crates.io/crates/twox-hash), I'll show that as an example:

```
use std::hash::BuildHasherDefault;
use std::collections::HashMap;
use twox_hash::XxHash;

let mut hash: HashMap<_, _, BuildHasherDefault<XxHash>> = Default::default();
hash.insert(42, "the answer");
assert_eq!(hash.get(&42), Some(&"the answer"));
```

---

That being said, *relying on the order of a `HashMap`* sounds like a bad idea. Perhaps you should use a different data structure, such as a [`BTreeMap`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.BTreeMap.html).

In other cases, you actually care about the order of **insertion**. For that, the [indexmap crate](https://crates.io/crates/indexmap) is appropriate.

Comment: Actually, the order of iteration in `indexmap` is not *strictly* the order of insertion. Why? Because when removing an element, the last inserted element is swapped with the element to be removed. It's still fully deterministic for a given sequence of insertions/removals.

Comment: Newer versions of `indexmap` apparently have a `shift_remove` function, which will preserve the insertion-order even after removals. See [here](https://github.com/bluss/indexmap/issues/220), [here](https://github.com/bluss/indexmap/issues/90), and [here](https://github.com/bluss/indexmap/pull/99) for some more info.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`HashMap::with_hasher()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#method.with_hasher) with something other than the default [`RandomState`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/hash_map/struct.RandomState.html).

Comment: for example... ?

Comment: @StepanYakovenko The [readme for HashMap](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html) says you can find alternative hashers with [this search](https://crates.io/keywords/hasher).

Answer (score 0):

The built-in [BTreeMap](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.BTreeMap.html) is a great option for this.

I was having a similar problem where the assert_eq! diff was in a random order each time, making debugging difficult for HashMap, but BTreeMap has sorted keys, so it doesn't have this problem.

(source: https://users.rust-lang.org/t/sort-hashmap-data-by-keys/37095/2)